# How to open all files in the folder (xls and csv format files) - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code for consolidate the data from multiple workbook to one workbook and the code only opening the xls format files but some files have csv format in the folder. how to open csv and xls files in the folder? Any suggestion it would appreciated

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportGroups()
Dim fPATH As String, fNAME As String
Dim LR As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim wb2, wb1 As Workbook, ofs As Worksheet

Set ofs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")


fPATH = "C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\MFI\"       

fNAME = Dir(fPATH & "*.xls")        'get the first filename in fpath

Do While Len(fNAME) > 0
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)   'open the file

    LastRow = ofs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ofs.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, -1).Value = fNAME

    Sheets("Input").Range("C8:J12").Copy
    ofs.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



    wb1.Close False   'close data workbook
        fNAME = Dir         'get the next filename
Loop


 LR = ofs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 ofs.Range("E2:I" & LR).Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 ofs.Range("A1:Z" & LR).Select
 With Selection
    WrapText = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all Files in the Folder and check then if the file is an CSV or xlsx File. And then Open it like you did.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub ImportGroups()
    Dim fPATH As String, fNAME As String
    Dim LR As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim wb2, wb1 As Workbook, ofs As Worksheet

    Set ofs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")


    fPATH = "C:\Users\ashokkumar.d\Desktop\MFI\"       

    fNAME = Dir(fPATH & "*.*")        'get the first filename in fpath

    Do While Len(fNAME) > 0
If Right(fNAME, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(fNAME, 4) = ".csv" Then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)   'open the file

        LastRow = ofs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ofs.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, -1).Value = fNAME

        Sheets("Input").Range("C8:J12").Copy
        ofs.Range("B" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



        wb1.Close False   'close data workbook
            fNAME = Dir         'get the next filename
end if
    Loop


     LR = ofs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     ofs.Range("E2:I" & LR).Select
     Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     ofs.Range("A1:Z" & LR).Select
     With Selection
        WrapText = True
        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
fNAME = Dir(fPATH & "*")        'get the first filename in fpath
Do While Len(fNAME) > 0
    dim ext as string, p as integer
    p = inStrRev(fName, ".")
    ext = ucase(mid(fName, p+1))
    if ext = "CSV" or ext = "XLS" or ext = "XLSX" or ext = "XLST" then
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fPATH & fNAME)   'open the file
        ...
    end if
```

Comment: 16 Sec late ^^. But your answer is better, because you have all the endings from excel in it. so 1+